# Exchange data between threads python

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I currently have this code:

```
def threaded_client(conn): 
     x_player1 = 120
     x_player2 = 560   
     a = 5
     b = 5
     data = {}   
     while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            z = data.decode('utf8')
            if z == '1':
              x_player1 = (x_player1 - a) 
              print("client1Left")
            elif z == '2':
              x_player1 = (x_player1 + b)
              print("client1Right")
            elif z == '3':
              x_player2 -= c 
              print("client2Left")
            elif z == '4':
              x_player2 += d 
              print("client2Right")
            data["player"] = {"x_player1": x_player1, 
                     "x_player2" : x_player2
            }
            s=json.dumps(data)
            return s

    while True:    
     conn, addr = server.accept()
     start_new_thread(threaded_client,(conn,))
```

When a client connects the program it creates a new thread. The only problem is that I want both threads to have the same value for x_player1 and x_player2.
I tried it with the queue module but I can't figure it out.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move `x_player1` and `x_player2` outside the client threads (the function `threaded_client`).  You could put them in a single object, which you will then pass to all the worker threads.  You would do this the same way as you are now passing the variable `conn`, although you don't give the function that does this, `start_new_thread`.

Now every thread can access the same two variables, `x_player1` and `x_player2`.  But you have to be careful that two threads don't try to mess with them at the same time.  Any time you need to modify them, you have to do so in a threadsafe manner.  For that you can use a Lock, which you can create in the same class.  I've given one example of the use of this lock when incrementing `x_player1`.  I used a context manager to acquire and release the lock.

```
class Players:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x_player1 = 120
        self.x_player2 = 500
        self.lock = threading.Lock()  # RLock is often better

    def increment_p1(self, n):
        with self.lock:
            self.x_player1 += n

    # similarly for decrement_p1, increment_p2, decrement_p2
```

I will point out that your program, as such, has at least one serious issue.  You have a `while True:` loop that always executes a return.  So it never actually loops, which can't be what you intend.

Comment: Thank you for your help! this will help me alot